# Does it harm if my bike to leave it in a workstand for 2 weeks?

Tags: mountain-bike

[image: If it hangs like this?]

If my Process 153 hangs like this in a workstand for two weeks does it cause any kind of harm?

Comment: The harm is from your wife wondering how long you're going to leave that thing sitting there.

Comment: Happy waifu, happy laifu.

Comment: The bike will suffer emotional hardship if you leave it like that too long. If you aren't going to be riding it or doing any work on it, you should read it a bedtime story so that it doesn't feel neglected. [Duck On A Bike](https://www.amazon.ca/Duck-Bike-David-Shannon/dp/0439050235/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1468453248&sr=1-1&keywords=duck+on+a+bike) might be a good one.

Answer (score 9):

No, it does not harm the bike.

Comment: To add to this, you're hanging it on the seat post. The seat post has constant tension on it when it is tightened to stay at a certain height, so it should be fine on the work stand.